# A very Puzzling Loss

Tags: calculation-puzzle

This question was asked by teacher, a very simple one but still highly puzzling. Could you find the answer?

> There were three persons, **A** :- The Costumer, **B** :- The Cloth Shop Owner and **C** :- A boot shop owner. The question goes:
>
> **A** purchased a cloth from **B** costing 200 rupees. Since **A** didn't had change he gave **B** a 1000 rupees note. **B** didn't had any change too. He went to **C** and brought 1000 in change and gave the remaining 800 rupees to **A** and **A** went away. After some time **C** went to **B** and said that the 1000 rupee note was fake. **B** returned 1000 rupees to **C**. How much did **B** Lose?

Sorry if the statements were bit puzzling. Ask if it is so.

Comment: @TylerSeacrest I knew it had to a duplicate, but I couldn't find it because I didn't think it was such a close duplicate.

Comment: It is not a duplicate, the other question is incomplete as it does not state if the 1000 was returned, so it becomes a debate of responsibility for the fake, while this question is solvable.